# Multiple social sharing buttons on a page for separate items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, social-networking

I have a plain HTML page with various images on it, each image when clicked opens a lightbox with sharing buttons inside. I had planned to use the ID in the URL to highlight which image the like was for, but it appears that facebook and twitter strip these out.

Without having hundreds of separate lightboxes for each image, how can I have sharing specific to the image currently being viewed?

HTML Examples:

```
        <div class="tile" id="tile-01">
            <a href="#tile-01" data-name="Jo" data-title="Chartered Surveyor">
                <img src="media/img01.jpg" alt="Jo" />
                <p class="name">Jo - Chartered Surveyor</p>
            </a>
        </div>

<div class="overlay">
    <div id="lightbox">
        <div class="lightbox-content">

        </div>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="close"></a>
        <div class="details">
            <h2>Claire</h2>
            <span class="job-title"></span>
            <div class="social">
                <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
                <a href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" ><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var $container = $('#gallery');
        $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
            $container.masonry();
        });

        $('.tile a').click(function(){
            $('.overlay').fadeIn();
            $img = $(this).find('img').clone();
            $('.lightbox-content').html($img)
            $('#lightbox h2').text($(this).data('name'))
            $('#lightbox span.job-title').text($(this).data('title'))
            return true;
        })

        $('.overlay').click(function(){
            $(this).fadeOut();
        })
    })
</script>
```